# The proof of the Morse index theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have a question regarding the proof of the Morse index theorem, which asserts that the index of the index form $I$ along a geodesic $\gamma\colon [0,l]\to M$ on a complete manifold is equal to the number of conjugate point $\gamma(t)$ ($t\in(0,l]$), counted with multiplicities.

The proof is roughly like the following (reference likes do Carmo's $\textit{Riemannian Geometry}$). If we let $i(t)$ be the index  and $d(t)$ be the nullity of the index form $I$ on $[0,t]\subseteq[0,l],$ then we have

(1) $i(t-\varepsilon)=i(t)$ for $\varepsilon$ small enough, and

(2) $i(t+ \varepsilon)=i(t)+d(t)$ for $\varepsilon>0$ small enough.

My question is, why will we need (1) to prove the index theorem? Can't we just use (2) above to derive the index theorem?  I mean, it seems (to me) that after we prove $d(t)$ is the multiplicity of the conjugate point $\gamma(t)$ if $d(t)>0,$ (2) then tells us the behavior of $i(t),$ and the result of the theorem. Am I correct?

Any comment is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You will need both since (ii) will only give you that $i(t)$ is right continuous if $d(t)=0$. But in order to conclude that $i(1)=\sum d(t_i)$ with conjugate points at $\gamma(t_i)$, $t_i \in (0,1)$ you will also need left continuity to show that in between to conjugate points i is continuous. As a counterexample consider the following function: $$i:[0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}_0$$ $$i(t)=\left\{\begin{array} {ll} 0 \text{ if } t \in [0,\frac{1}{3}] \\
1 \text{ if } t \in (\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}) \\
0 \text{ if } t \in [\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3}] \\
1 \text{ if } t \in (\frac{2}{3},1] \end{array} \right.$$ This function satisfies (ii) $i(t+\epsilon)=i(t)+d(t)$ for $\epsilon$ small enough and $d(t)=1$ for $t\in \{\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}\}$ and $d(t)=0$ else; but this function is not left-continuous and we can see $i(1)=1\neq 2=\sum d(t)$.